# What happens if I don't set 'number of reduce tasks' in my mapreduce program?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know what will happen if I don't include the `setNumReduceTasks()` in my mapreduce program's Driver class at all. What default value would it take?

Once I wrote a MapReduce Java program and didn't `setNumReduceTasks()` in my code. But the monitoring app still showed many Reducers running.

Why is this?

Comment: The default value is 1

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have an entry for **mapreduce.job.reduces** in mapred-site.xml it would default to 1.Else it would take the value from mapred-site.xml

Comment: If getpartition() method returns 1(0 - first reducer and so on) but you have set your number of reducers to 1. Then the records coming out of partition1 would be thrown away. Usually the practice is to use a modulo of numReduceTasks while returning, so that you don't fall under this case. Something like this would help. return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;